# Apache redirection without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias

Here is the URL I want to display : m.mywebsite.com
Here is the directory where the data are : home/mywebsite/www/m

Here my Apache conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www2/m
<Directory /home/mywebsite/sd/m/www>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
SuexecUserGroup mywebsite users
ServerName m.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that when I launch http://m.mywebsite.com, there is a 301 redirection to http://www.mywebsite.com/m
I want to keep http://m.mywebsite.com URL that display the content of this directory : /home/mywebsite/www2/m

Thanks !

Comment: Your configuration seems to be correct, and definitely there aren't redirects to www.mywebsite.com

You should post the `VirtualHost` or the `.htaccess` used for www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace :

```
DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www2/m
<Directory /home/mywebsite/sd/m/www>
```

by :

```
DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www2/m
<Directory /home/mywebsite/www2/m>
```

In order to see content of http://www.mywebsite.com/m when reaching this URL : http://m.mywebsite.com/